# Do I need to enter US from the country where I got my visa?

Tags: visas, usa

Will there be a problem for me arriving in the US if I arrive from Pakistan rather then Thailand where I received my B1/B2 visa?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: I mean to say i work in bangkok and have got U.S visa,which was obviously applied from bangkok. If i anyhow shift to Pakistan again and would wish to visit U.S on this visa ..will it create any problem?

Comment: Its about the place where it is applied from and from the other state i wish to visit it ?

Comment: I meant it will be possible to visit U.S from Pakistan, is applied from bangkok.???

Comment: Having a certain visa is different than having a certain passport. Visas might be useful in certain cases such as transit flights, but that's it..

Comment: Duplicate of: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10090/does-my-b1-b2-visa-for-the-us-permit-me-to-travel-there-from-anywhere-or-just-m

Answer (score 1):

In most cases the immigration officers do not know where you come from when you show up at their desk, as people coming in on several flights arrive at once.

Besides, visa do not include prescribed flight routes, you could have found a better deal with an airline that goes through Pakistan which is a very common thing.

So, no, it does not matter as long as your passport and visa are correct for your stay.

You can not apply for visa if not resident in most countries now but in the past you used to get a visa for the next country from the one you where, or for one a few countries ahead, traveling any way you could.